# SKLabelNodeなどのようなクラスを自作したい

Tags: swift

いつもお世話になっております。

組み込まれたクラスのように便利なクラスをswiftで作成したいと考えております。
例えば、初期化後のインスタンスに、後からプロパティ変数で値を渡し、その値を表示させるような簡単なクラスを考えております。

画面に出力する機能を自作するのではなく、後から設定したプロパティ変数の値を、インスタンス内のプロパティやメソッド指定なしに直接インスタンス参照し表示できるクラスになります。

ご教授ご鞭撻のほどよろしくお願い致します。

```
let node = SKLabelNode()  // 初期化
node.text = "abc"  // 初期化後にインスタンス変数に値を設定
self.addChild(node)  // "abc"でなく"ABC"が表示される(インスタンス内のプロパティやメソッド指定なしに直接インスタンス参照し表示)
node.text = "ABC"  // 後から値を変更
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: タグの説明にも書いてありますが、[swift3] タグや [swift4] タグは、ご質問の内容がそのバージョンの Swift に関係するときだけ使用し、かわりに [swift] タグをご使用ください。単にバージョン情報を示しているだけなのであれば、本文中に環境情報として追記するのが良いと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。タグをswiftにしました。